# pdf creator in window8

Tags: cordova, pdf, windows-8.1

I  have created an hybrid application for windows 8 at first. I have the necessity to create a pdf for a purchase order. I want to do this with native code. It is a good idea? I use angular framework. Do you know any implementation of that that can help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Check if the below links helps:

```
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Operate-PDF-file-in-C-585605ef#content

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.data.pdf.pdfdocument?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=javascript#code-snippet-1
```

If already API's are available in WinJS you could directly use the same.